# WebStorm execute TSLint on shortcut

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, ide, webstorm, tslint

I want to use TSLint to autofix current errors in opened file (not whole project). I can do it by writing `tslint $FilePathRelativeToProjectRoot$ --fix` in console, but I rather want to create custom shortcut or as trigger on file save.

Does someone has an experience with this kind of set up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up TSLint as a [file watcher](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2019.1/settings-tools-file-watchers.html):

[image]

make sure to clear **Auto-save edited files to trigger the watcher** checkbox to have the watcher triggered on explicit **Save all** action (`Ctrl+S`)

Comment: I struggle with arguments (Invalid option for configuration: tslint.json), but after i change them to '-c $ProjectFileDir$/tslint.json --fix $FilePath$' it works.